# Jenkins Master - Docker Slave: Build shows error

Tags: docker, jenkins

Using Master on Windows VM whereas tried to spin container in linux container. Kindly help to resolve this.

> Even some idea/ guidance would be of great help.

- hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder withJarCacheOrDefault WARNING: **Could not 
  create jar cache**. Running 
  without cache.
- java.io.IOException:**Failed to initialize the default JAR Cache location**
- Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/jenkins/?  \
- Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Root directory not 
  writable**: ?/.jenkins/cache/jars

Answer (score 0):

Looks like permission issue.

1. Does the Windows VM has write permission for the Linux Container?

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/jenkins/? \
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Root directory not writable: ?/.jenkins/cache/jars
```

In Linux Container did you verified above path exists or not?